# maxmemory parameter in redis.conf

Tags: redis

I am trying to insert key-"value" in redis.The "value" is of X  bytes while leaving my application to be inserted in redis. I want to know which parameter to monitor after firing "INFO" command from ./redis-cli to check that X(or perhaps  X + somevalue , in case redis pads some data) number of bytes have been used in redis.Am doing this to determine the maxmemory(redis.conf) parameter needed for my application.

I have one master and a sentinel and am using redis for transient storage.I have tried monitoring the used_memory parameter. But as per the data i got it seems that maxmemory is not related to used_memory.

So instead I was thinking of using "debug object Mykey" which gives the serializedlength.What exactly is this length , I could not find any description in redis docs.

So basically two questions :

1. Are maxmemory and used_memory related ,if yes then is there some catch in using used_memory to calculate space occupied by the inserted key-value.
2. What is serializedlength in the "debug object Mykey" command

Answer (score 0):

1. The `maxmemory` configuration directive dictates the maximum amount of memory that Redis should be allowed to use for user data. When set to 0 (the default value), Redis will allocate memory as long as the underlying OS will allow it. The `used_memory` value from the `INFO` command is the actual memory consumed by user data at the time that the command was invoked. The relationship between the two (as long is `maxmemory` isn't 0) is `used_memory` <= `maxmemory`.
2. The `serializedlength` outputted by `DEBUG OBJECT` is the length (size in bytes) of the value stored under that key when serialized. To obtain the actual serialized value you can use the [`DUMP`](http://redis.io/commands/dump) command. Note that the serialized length **does not** provide an accurate measure of the actual amount of memory that's used by the key due to a myriad of factors including Redis' encoding of the data structure and overheads.

Generally, in order to obtain an estimate for your `maxmemory` setting, try storing a few 100s (e.g. 1000) keys that are representative of your data, check the `used_memory` afterwards, divide the value and then multiply the result by the number of expected keys with a safe margin (e.g. at least %10).

Comment: "The used_memory value from the INFO command is the actual memory consumed by user data at the time that the command was invoked."
Does the memory consumed by user data change after completion of command?


Just for clarification what you are suggesting is suppose i insert X keys  in redis. I should divide user_memory by X and the resultant should give me memory used by each key.

Also I noticed that used_memory is around 370 kb even when no command is issued to redis (dont know why). That too will need some accounting when estimating "maxmemory" using "used_memory"?

Comment: `INFO` does not affect memory usage. You're right about the 370kb overhead, of course, and it could vary slightly. Usually it becomes negligible when your put some data in. You got the division right, but remember it is only a rough estimate. You can do more/bigger iterations to get a better feel for the numbers.

Comment: What about the size of client-output-buffer. If that is considered then we will need to have any estimate of how many clients we are serving and the average client output buffer size.
Then this value should also be added for estimation of maxmemory?

Comment: All buffers play an important role in the memory consumption of Redis. The client buffer can grow large when the client is slow and/or there are large replies. If you find that the default setting doesn't work for you, you'll need to change it and provision for it.

Comment: but then again redis.conf states "if you have slaves attached it is suggested that you set a lower
 limit for maxmemory so that there is some free RAM on the system for slave
 output buffers (but this is not needed if the policy is 'noeviction')."
This is quite confusing .To me it suggests that memory consumption of output buffer for slaves is not included in maxmemory and is seperately taken up from system RAM.(clueless why the doc says we dont need free RAM for "noeviction" )

Comment: Indeed - all buffers are outside the maxmemory setting.