# Redis performance testing

Tags: redis, jmeter, performance-testing

So I want to test redis by shooting 1000 set commands per sec and observe if the RAM usage shoots above a certain limit.
I tried using redis-benchmark but it does not provide the facility to limit the rate to 1000 set command per nor can i set an expiry for keys.
Also it simply returns the number of requests per second.

Also am going to use jedis client .I thought of using Jmeter to accomplish the above. Would that be a feasible option or is there any other tool or facility that redis provides to accomplish the same.

Comment: "shooting 1000 set commands per sec and observe if the RAM usage shoots above a certain limit" - to be blunt, your test doesn't make much sense. why are you doing this?

Comment: just need to know how much data would redis be able to handle without causing RAM problems

Comment: so the temporal nature of your test is really irrelevant...

Comment: Writing a client to add data at no more than 1000 sets is nearly trivial, but that won't get you what you seek to be looking for. Do you know the data you are adding in? That will be key to determining how much memory you need. If you can be more specific we can help you better. This doesn't seem to about performance, but figuring out how much memory you need to have. Redis can swamp a 1G network easily and 1000 sets per second is trivial to Redis. For an rough guideline on figuring out memory requirements see https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/redis-db/02oq_DNZA3s/l_uEwDT3d4sJ

Comment: to be more specific i have the amount of memory my keys are going to use in redis. But I am not sure what else I need to consider while estimate RAM .This is the specific situation I am facing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369314/maxmemory-parameter-in-redis-conf/
Also thanks for that link.In the 8 steps given in that link to estimate RAM  the person has mentioned to "calculate the size of the dump for 
initial slaving".What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

There is [Redis Data Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/) extension which adds Redis load testing functionality into JMeter.

In order to set exact requests rate you can use [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer).